# Kubernetes pod cpu usage calculation method for HPA

Tags: docker, kubernetes, autoscaling

Can someone explain how the cpu usage is calculated inside pods with multiple containers for use with an Horizontal Pod Autoscaler?
Is it the mean value and how is this calculated?

For example:
If we have 2 containers:

- Container1 requests 0.5 cpu and uses 0 cpu
- Container2 requests 1 cpu    and uses 2 cpu

If we calculate both seperatly and take the mean: (0% + 200%)/2 = 100% usage?

If we take the sums and take the mean: 2/1.5 = 133% usage?

Or is my logic way off?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of kubernetes 1.9 HPA calculates pod cpu utilization as total cpu usage of all containers in pod divided by total request. So in your example the calculated usage would be 133%. I don't think that's specified in docs anywhere, but the relevant code is here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.9.0/pkg/controller/podautoscaler/metrics/utilization.go#L49

However, I would consider this an implementation detail. As such it can easily change in future versions.

Comment: I think  that this doc is outdated now, do you have one more up-to-date?

Comment: I tried switching the branch to master and the code remained the same. So the math stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

In the Horizontal Pod Autoscaling design documentation it's clearly written that it takes the arithmetic mean of the pods' CPU utilization to compare against the target value. Here is the text:

> The autoscaler is implemented as a control loop. It periodically
>   queries pods described by Status.PodSelector of Scale subresource, and
>   collects their CPU utilization. Then, it compares the arithmetic mean
>   of the pods' CPU utilization with the target defined in
>   Spec.CPUUtilization, and adjusts the replicas of the Scale if needed
>   to match the target (preserving condition: MinReplicas <= Replicas <=
>   MaxReplicas).

The target number of pods is calculated from the following formula:

```
TargetNumOfPods = ceil(sum(CurrentPodsCPUUtilization) / Target)
```

For further detail: https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/autoscaling/horizontal-pod-autoscaler.md

Comment: If I understand correctly this info is about how to calculate how many pods the HPA needs to start. It does not state how it calculates the pod cpu usage if multiple containers are inside the pod. I think my question still stands.

Comment: This describes how the autoscaler takes into account the CPU usage of each pod in a set of pods, not of each container in a set of pods.