# How does Kubernetes Horizontal Pod Autoscaler calculate CPU Utilization for Multi Container Pods?

Tags: api, kubernetes, containers, autoscaling, horizontal-scaling

**Question 1.)**

**Given the scenario a multi-container pod, where all containers have a defined CPU request:

How would Kubernetes Horizontal Pod Autoscaler calculate CPU Utilization for Multi Container pods?**  

Does it average them? (((500m cpu req + 50m cpu req) /2) * X% HPA target cpu utilization 
Does it add them? ((500m cpu req + 50m cpu req) * X% HPA target cpu utilization 
Does it track them individually? (500m cpu req * X% HPA target cpu utilization = target #1, 50m cpu req * X% HPA target cpu utilization = target #2.) 

**Question 2.)** 
**Given the scenario of a multi-container pod, where 1 container has a defined CPU request and a blank CPU request for the other containers: 

How would Kubernetes Horizontal Pod Autoscaler calculate CPU Utilization for Multi Container pods?**
Does it work as if you only had a 1 container pod?

**Question 3.)** 
**Do the answers to questions 1 and 2 change based on the HPA API version?** 
I noticed stable/nginx-ingress helm chart, chart version 1.10.2, deploys an HPA for me with these specs:

```yaml
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
```

(I noticed apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2 now exists)

**Background Info:**

 I recently had an issue with unexpected wild scaling / constantly going back and forth between min and max pods after adding a sidecar(2nd container) to an nginx ingress controller deployment (which is usually a pod with a single container). In my case, it was an oauth2 proxy, although I image istio sidecar container folks might run into this sort of problem all the time as well.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx-ingress-controller #(primary-container)
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 500m    #baseline light load usage in my env 
              memory: 2Gi  #according to kubectl top pods
            limits:
              memory: 8Gi  #(oom kill pod if this high, because somethings wrong)
        - name: oauth2-proxy #(newly-added-2nd-sidecar-container)
          resources: 
            requests:
              cpu: 50m
              memory: 50Mi
            limits:
              memory: 4Gi
```

I have an HPA (apiVersion: autoscaling/v1) with:

- min 3 replicas (to preserve HA during rolling updates)
- targetCPUUtilizationPercentage = 150%

**It occurred to me that my misconfiguration leads to unexpected wild scaling was caused by 2 issues:**

1. I don't actually understand how HPAs work when the pod has multiple containers
2. I don't know how to dig deep to get metrics of what's going on.

---

**To address the first issue: I brainstormed my understanding of how it works in the single container scenario** (and then realized I don't know the multi-container scenario so I decided to ask this question)

**This is my understanding of how HPA (autoscaling/v1) works when I have 1 container (temporarily ignore the 2nd container in the above deployment spec):**

The HPA would spawn more replicas when the CPU utilization average of all pods shifted from my normal expected load of 500m or less to 750m (150% x 500m request)

---

**To address the 2nd issue: I found out how to dig to see concrete numeric value-based metrics vs relative percentage-based metrics to help figure out what's happening behind the scenes:**

```sh
bash# kubectl describe horizontalpodautoscaler nginx-ingress-controller -n=ingress | grep Metrics: -A 1
Metrics:                                               ( current / target )
  resource cpu on pods  (as a percentage of request):  5% (56m) / 100%
```

(Note: kubectl top pods -n=ingress, showed cpu usage of the 5 replicas as 36m, 34m, 88m, 36m, 91m, so that 57m current which ~matches 56m current)

Also now it's a basic proportions Math Problem that allows solving for target static value: 
(5% / 56m) = (100% / x m) --> x = 56 * 100 / 5 = 1120m target cpu

 (Note: this HPA isn't associated with the deployment mentioned above, that's why the numbers are off.)

Comment: You can look at https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#how-does-the-horizontal-pod-autoscaler-work for the implementation details.

Comment: The documented implementation details only describe what happens at the pod level. My question is asked specificially because what happens at the container level (multi-container pods) seems to be undocumented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basing on stackoverflow community member answer in other [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48172151/kubernetes-pod-cpu-usage-calculation-method-for-hpa)

> "HPA calculates pod cpu utilization as total cpu usage of all containers in pod divided by total request. I don't think that's specified in docs anywhere, but the relevant code is [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.9.0/pkg/controller/podautoscaler/metrics/utilization.go#L49)"

You have got more informations,with examples in the link above.

---

Basing on documentation

[Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) automatically scales the number of pods in a replication controller, deployment or replica set based on observed CPU utilization (or, **with beta support, on some other, application-provided metrics**).

So basically:

[apiVersion](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#api-object) autoscaling/v1 HPA base on **cpu**.

apiVersion autoscaling/v2beta2 base on **cpu,memory,custom metrics**.

More informations [here](https://rancher.com/blog/2018/2018-08-06-k8s-hpa-resource-custom-metrics/)

Comment: Link to source code is golden. That's kind of dumb you could have 1GB req + 10mb req, but when it averages it'll use 505mb as the target... That's exactlly why I had wild scaling to max unexpectedly. It seems that if the 2nd container has no request, it'll be ignored / the HPA will treat the container as if it only had 1 request

Answer (score 0):

For question 2 if we look at [source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/2e7996e3e2712684bc73f0dec0200d64eec7fe40/pkg/controller/podautoscaler/replica_calculator.go#L411) we can see that it looks all containers individually and returns if container doesn't have request.

```
func calculatePodRequests(pods []*v1.Pod, resource v1.ResourceName) (map[string]int64, error) {
   requests := make(map[string]int64, len(pods))
   for _, pod := range pods {
      podSum := int64(0)
      for _, container := range pod.Spec.Containers {
         if containerRequest, ok := container.Resources.Requests[resource]; ok {
            podSum += containerRequest.MilliValue()
         } else {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("missing request for %s", resource)
         }
      }
      requests[pod.Name] = podSum
   }
   return requests, nil
}
```

---

---